# Power BI - Drill through filter isn't working for date columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, drillthrough

I'm pretty new in Power BI and have a problem with the drill-through filter.
[image: Filter]

Here is what my table looks like:
[image]

When I add a drill-through filter on another report page, I can't use on this page `right click-> drill-through` whereas if I add a filter for the rows (KSt in this case) it works. I've tested it with several data types and everything except the date format seems to work. Do you have any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: That's strange, I've never encountered that issue before. Did you enable the drill-through feature on both pages with the same field?

Comment: I added the time period filter to the drill through page and that's it. With other parameters it semms to work but for this one it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I solved this issue by selecting `Time Period` instead of `Date Hierarchy`. Now the drill-through filter works.

[image: Drill through]